# OSX Lion 10.7.3 FREEZES on Macbook pro 13'' 2009

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I've got a macbook pro 13" mid 2009 and I upgraded to OSX Lion immediately when it came out. Never had any problem with it. Also I upgraded to 8 Gb a few weeks ago (because I use a virtual machine (win 7) + Adobe applications at the same time) and that seemed to work just fine.

Since a week or so, the OS seems to freez all the time. Just typing this message it happened more than 6 times. 
By Freeze I mean that the system doesn't seem to react for 10 seconds or more, and sometimes it shows the spinning wheel (waiting sign).

I did a clean install of Lion yesterday, but this didn't solve the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd point the problem to two possible culprits: 1) Faulty Memory. 2) Hard drive failing…

Comment: Is there a way to test the hard drive? Because I am almost certain it's not the memory failing.

Comment: I'd take it to an appstore so the genius can run the diagnostics